# Taylors series approximation error

Tags: real-analysis

In a taylors' series approximation upto what term do you use to find the error?
E.g. in my notes for log(x) they have worked out upto the nth derivative of log(x) and lets call it $f^{(n)}(x)$, they substituted $t$ in for $x$ and worked out error how you normally would but for the function $(x+1)logx$ they have said you only need to work out upto the third derivative and substitute t in for x in the third derivative function and thus work out the error.

I dont see the reason behind this.

Comment: The question is not very clear. The degree at which you truncate the series depends on the context (and sometimes you only know you need more after you failed to conclude). In what case exactly do you need third derivative?

Comment: for $(x+1)logx$ they only need the third derivative to calculate the error term but for $logx$ they use the nth derivative to calculate the error term and im not sure why

Comment: Well, as is, there is no reason whatsoever to truncate at some order instead of another. Maybe you are just asked to do this as an exercise. In other circumstances, for instance the computation of limits, the truncation order is very important: too low and you have not enough information, too high and it get overly complicated. Note that the abscissa where you take the Taylor series is also very important.

Comment: For  many applications, rarely is more than a quadratic estimate required.  And, so you would need the 3rd derivative to estimate the error.  But, if more precision was required you could use a longer Taylor series and use a higher order derivative to estimate the error.